# Magento 2: Get CMS Page content - from API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Hi all @magento developer,

I am using Magento inbuild API, domain.com/rest/V1/cmsPage/13

& the response is not like what I want.

```
{
    "id": 13,
    "identifier": "page2",
    "title": "Find Page",
    "page_layout": "1column",
    "meta_title": "",
    "meta_keywords": "",
    "meta_description": "",
    "content_heading": "Find a Rep",
    "content": "{{block class=\"Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block\" block_id=\"rep_page\"}}",
    "creation_time": "2018-09-14 18:33:51",
    "update_time": "2019-05-29 18:58:29",
    "sort_order": "0",
    "layout_update_xml": "",
    "custom_theme": "",
    "custom_root_template": "",
    "active": true
}
```

In the above response, you can see  `"content": "{{block class=\"Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block\" block_id=\"rep_page\"}}",`

& this block contains actual information of the page. So my question is if there is any way to get content of **block_id = rep_page** withpout using another API **/rest/V1/cmsBlock/{block_id}**.

Comment: Check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way. The solution is using the `FilterProvider` to parse the page's content, this way, it'll parse everything with parameter like block, widget, etc to their html content.

Detailed approach:

- **Step 1: Create a plugin to modify the API response processor:**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceOutputProcessor">
        <plugin name="vendor_module_webapi_service_output_processor_plugin"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Webapi\ServiceOutputProcessorPlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

- **Step 2: parse the page's content and save it to the response data:**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Webapi/ServiceOutputProcessorPlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Webapi;

use Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider;
use Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceOutputProcessor;

class ServiceOutputProcessorPlugin
{
    protected $filterProvider;

    public function __construct(FilterProvider $filterProvider)
    {
        $this->filterProvider = $filterProvider;
    }

    public function beforeProcess(
        ServiceOutputProcessor $subject,
        $data,
        $serviceClassName,
        $serviceMethodName
    ) {
        if ($serviceClassName == 'Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface' && $serviceMethodName == 'getById') {
            $content = $data->getContent();
            $parsedContent = $this->filterProvider->getPageFilter()->filter($content);
            $data->setContent($parsedContent);
            return [$data, $serviceClassName, $serviceMethodName];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tailtiu,Thanks for your solution, For block, its working fine {{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="men-block"}}. but calling template file using widget its not working Eg:<p>{{widget type="Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block" template="widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="20"}}</p>. Do you have any solution for calling template file.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this magento api](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_22.html#/cmsBlockRepositoryV1) :
[image]

Comment: but what we will do, when there is multiple blocks is calling in a single CMS page. I don't want to use cmsBlock plugin.